# Why was my not-an-answer (NAA) flag declined?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, declined-flags

All [this "answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33247562/3001626) says is that my solution doesn't return the exact column order as before (while the question was about "*how to return the rest of the columns*" while order wasn't mentioned at all by the OP) **without providing any alternative solution while just copy pasting my solution + rant**.

How is that an answer rather than just a comment/rant?

---

Snip for lower reputation-points users

[image]

Comment: I did flag it as NAA as well, but that was also declined. As David explained, it is just a comment.

Comment: *"sorry for the blur as this is what happens to -3 answers"* This blur will "go away" if you hover your mouse on this answer.

Comment: @Tom I was unsuccessful to sync it with my snipping tool though, but I think I finally managed

Comment: I flagged that answer as well, also declined.

Comment: I would love to know who is downvoting this and for what reason. Is there anyone here thinks that the linked answer is indeed an answer?

Comment: If they had allowed comments on the flag you could've commented *I am David A and this is not an answer* :-D But alas, they don't allow :-(

Comment: @BhargavRao you can add description on on a custom flag though. This is basically what rene suggests.

Comment: Hehe, @DavidA you did not get my comment. It was on a humorous note. Explaining the joke  -- The answer has someone called David A whom the reviewers won't know. So as you are "the David A" and if there was a message you could have added "I am the David A" mentioned in the answer. Hope you got it (*Marks another joke as PJ in the diary*)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem with not an answer flags when handled by moderators is their lack of context. They don't see any other answers or the question, they only see the content of that answer. Let's try it how you would do:

> You do get your columns back in a different order if you use David A's "everything()" approach, `"select(iris, petal = starts_with("Petal"), everything())"`

If you only see this you have no idea who David A is (really, who are you?) nor what or where his approach is mentioned. Without that context it might be an attempt to answer. Hence the moderator declines your flag.

There are a lot of mishaps with NAA flags. If you are unsure if your NAA would be recognized when presented in isolation use a custom flag instead and explain what you want to happen and why. In this case you could have asked if the answer could be converted to a comment under your answer.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I'll try to keep that in mind next time. Not sure regarding the *really, who are you?* part though :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg  You know where to find me if you want to sort that out .. ;)

Comment: *"Without that context it might be an attempt to answer. Hence the moderator declines your flag."* This always sounds very strange to me. Then they don't see the context, then why don't skip this if they are unsure? Since the community can see the context in the "Low Quality Posts" review queue, it could be handled by them instead.

Comment: Moderators don't skip ...

Comment: Are they not allowed to skip? If yes, then this restriction is very odd if they review the same stuff as the community. Would be understandable for "special" moderator flags so something, but not for an NAA flag.

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think mods like to NOT handle a flag as that would simply mean they push the workload to the next mod... after 18 such pushes the flag is back to the first mod...

Comment: Well, then there should be a "let the community handle this" button for flags which are also reviewed by the community :D.

Comment: @Tom - Every "not an answer" flag is already presented to the community for review. The problem is that the community *isn't* handling these in a timely fashion, so it falls to moderators to deal with them. If the community can't figure out what to do with them, and neither can we, "not an answer" wasn't the right choice to use for a flag on a post. That flag is there for fast-tracked processing of obvious non-answers that require immediate deletion.

Comment: @BradLarson Thank you for your feedback. I know that these flags are also reviewed by the community, but I never heared, that "time" is also an important point here. And I don't see why it should be important. Since the flag popup states several reasons for posts being not an answer it may take some time to review that. So I still don't know why a moderator need to take the time to review these flags as well. If that post really requires immeditate deletion, like spam, harassing posts etc., than there are better flags for that.

Comment: @Tom - There are currently nearly 600 "not an answer" flags awaiting review. The oldest of these has been in review for nearly two weeks without the community taking any action on it. The point of this flag is to provide cases we can identify and delete at a glance. While I do regularly pull up the full question to figure out why someone would have flagged something that way, requiring this of every flag of this type does not scale for normal reviewers or moderators. It's better to provide any non-obvious context in the flag itself, to make sure we see what you did.

Comment: Seems like standard practice for moderators should *always* be to go to the source location of the question/comment/answer, because **context is key** when determining the outcome of moderation intervention.

Comment: @TylerH: I also think **context is key** before enforcing policies such as that. Moderators process over a thousand flags a day. It is untenable to ask us to check the context of each and every one of those flags before processing it. The one or two mistakes you see posted in meta are a tiny fraction of the flags we process.

Comment: @Matt I disagree that it's untenable to ask you to check the context of each flag. In fact I think it's untenable that you would suggest otherwise in the first place. If your workload is too large, elect more moderators, don't pare back your own quality control simple because "big work load".

Comment: The real questions here are: (1) Why do moderators apply, or have to apply, different rules from what mere mortals in the NAA queue use? (2) Why aren't they provided with the same level of information? (3) Why do they get involved at all? (4) How can we possibly be expected to know in advance whether an NAA flag will be moderated or queued? There are several things seriously wrong here.