# Do moderators see comments under flagged posts?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderator-tools

I did not find an existing Q/A on the subject.

After [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308472/3627607) on another meta post I have doubts.

Usually when I flag a post and feel the flag is not obvious or need explanation I comment under the post to inform the author of why I flag it with the idea a moderator will also see this comment and will have more information on my point of view.

Am I wrong with this assumption or is it a correct way to inform the moderators while teaching authors at the same time?

I'm not saying everyone should do it like this or wishing to change the system; I just wish feedback on how I handle flagging usually.

Comment: The moderators can *see* all comments (even deleted ones), but whether an given moderator *reads* the comments on a given question will surely depend on, among other things, what you've written in your flag. Make their lives easier: put everything they need in the flag. Imagine there are dozens of comments, should they really need to read through all of them to do their job?

Comment: @jonrsharpe You mean raising a custom flag when the reason I flag for is not obvious or need more context ?

Comment: I assumed you were referring *only* to custom flags. The guidance is to *"Be specific and detailed!"*

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think Tens knows they can see comments (not sure regarding deleted once though), but the question is: in their tool which they use, do comments appear too or *just* the answer itself (without any additional context- as per the linked answer). Regarding putting everything in the flag, he stated that he wants the OP to see it too.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I suggest you don't assume that the moderator will read through the comments (whether or not they see them!) If you think more information than the pre-canned flag is required to handle it correctly, raise a custom flag.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was talking about flags where there can be ambiguity or a knowledge of the context/domain is needed to get with. I can raise a custom flag, and do when I see no point trying to educate the OP.  I'm more asking about non obvious cases, where I wish to let the OP know what I think and give details to my flag at the same time instead of repeating myself in a custom flag

Comment: If *"knowledge of the context/domain is needed"* then it's probably not appropriate for a moderator to be dealing with it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe _"then it's probably not appropriate for a moderator to be dealing with it."_ could you say more on your idea ? Why not ? on low traffic tags it could take month before a question comes on hold or be cleaned, years for a bad answer...

Comment: Because the moderators *probably don't have that domain knowledge*. SO covers a wide range of topics and has only 18 moderators! I suggest reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators and the linked resources.

Comment: Feel free to drop a link in the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) if you need more eyes on something that is attracting crap in low traffic tags @Tensibai

Comment: @jonrsharpe I didn't had the feeling the moderators should not handle flags in domain they don't master...

Comment: @Tensibai it's not that they shouldn't handle the flags, but that you shouldn't be raising moderator flags for *technical issues* relating to the language/toolkit in question. If an answer has a security vulnerability, for example, that isn't something you should be asking a moderator to adjudicate.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I agree on this last point, I can't find an example of what I mean actually, I'll raise a new question if I find one to get advice on how to handle it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To directly answer your question...

> Do moderators see comments under flagged posts?

There are 3 view states for a post.

1. Collapsed. This is the default. We **don't** see any comments.
2. Expanded. We can click a collapsed post to reveal more information. Here, we see a "show n more comments" link, but still **can't** see individual comments.
3. Expanded, with comments. Upon clicking the "show n more comments" link, we'd end up in this state, and **can** *now* see the comments on a post.

Now, reading between the lines on the comments under your post...

> On low traffic tags it could take month before a question comes on hold or be cleaned.

If you're asking a moderator to place a question on hold, or delete it, you're already raising a custom flag. As jon alluded to in comments, and given the above (how moderators don't always see comments on flags), I'd include as much information in the flag as possible (even copy/ paste what you left as a comment, if you wish).

> It could take years for a bad answer [... to be removed]

A bad (wrong) answer should be downvoted, not removed. It shouldn't take domain knowledge to spot answers-which-aren't-answers.

Comment: Just to ensure I properly understood your last point. An answer not exactly answering the question and giving a potentially dangerous solution should only be downvoted and commented accordingly ? (asking to correct my behavior for those cases)

Comment: @Tensibai: If the answer is not *attempting* to answer the question, then flag it as NAA. Otherwise, a downvote and comment is sufficient.

Comment: Ok, I see the idea, I can't find an example of what I've in mind actually but I will raise another question on a specific case for it ;)

Comment: @Tensibai: Yes. In fact, downvoted bad answers, with comments explaining *why* they're bad, can actually be useful as examples of what *not* to do. This is especially true in cases where the answer describes an obvious but incorrect solution or a popular misconception. Leaveing such answers undeleted can also deter new visitors from repeatedly posting the same wrong answer again.