# Can I assume an *answer to an unasked question* to be or not to be an answer?

Tags: discussion

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) I thought, I learned that when I ask:

> How much is the apple?

the response:

> If you want to buy a car, make sure you have enough money.

is not an answer. Arguable it is an answer. *It is just the wrong question!*

However I thought I might flag an [*answer to the wrong question*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43835599/2056452) as *not an answer* - which I obviously got wrong. So I got the explaination:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Should I have flagged the question instead, because the OP was just not able to ask the correct question?

---

Or as Shakespear might have asked:
**Can I assume an *answer to an unasked question* to be or not to be an answer?**

Comment: I'd just downvote the answer and (if warranted and useful) point out that it's not an answer to the question asked. It's too much to ask from moderators that they carefully read question and answer (in a field they may know nothing about) and then weigh whether it's an answer about the apple or not. That's why "not an answer" is limited to *obvious* non-answers

Comment: Then it would be nice to allow to add a short comment to each flag and not only *in need for moderator intervention* - which would be way too dramatic for this case. And for the moderator, if he has no expertise on the field, I think it is better to let the *flag age away*. If I'd review answers and this would be an audit I would have failed. So if I don't know whether it is legit or not, I skip it. I think, that is what moderators should do as well, if they can't decide it.

Comment: @derM There's a reason for the custom message moderator flag, it's exactly for cases where pre-baked reasons doesn't exactly fit or could not be obvious to everyone.

Comment: Related [meta.se post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: Why involve a moderator in this at all? Just downvote.

Comment: @Tensibai: I already linked this post. First word of my post. In this post *Shog9* specifically sais: Oranges are no answers when apples are asked. So this completely fits this description.

Comment: @Pekka웃: Why are there review queues for all kind of stuff, when you can down-vote everything. Why are there flags at all for non-offensive stuff, when it is better not to use them, but to *down-vote*?

Comment: This one: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308467/3627607 should be a better explanation

Comment: @Tensibai: I don't see how your last link should be realted, because there the answer is about the topic at least. Here we have a code that explains how to call an external program from java, when the question was about parsing data in excell.

Comment: Ok, I'll extend my thoughts in an answer

Comment: That would be very appreciated!

Comment: This doesn't apply to this specific case, but sometimes answers that don't answer the question are justified, and that is when the OP is asking about something which is bad or obsolete practice.

Then it is fine to post an answer explaining why the things asked for in the question shouldn't be used. In particular, this is helpful for others than the OP, that might stumble upon the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically for NAA flags, the view from moderators is quite restricted, they see the answer in isolation.

Let's take the answer you're targetting:

> ```
> import java.io.*;
> import java.util.*;
> public class image {
> public static void main(String[] args){
> Runtime Rt;
> Process Prc;
> String cmd = "";
> cmd ="sqlldr userID/password@DB control=cntr.ctl log=log1.log" ;
> Rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
> try {
> Prc = Rt.exec(cmd);}
> catch(Exception exception)
>         {
>             exception.printStackTrace();
>         }
> }
> }
> ```

It's indeed poor, no explanation of what it does, however there's a call to sqlldr somewhere, I've no clue what this program does, from an external point of view on a question named *"Excel/CSV - Convert key value to csv"* that may be something related which does what the question is about.

Even if it is bad or wrong, it looks like an honest attempt to answer and not blatantly something else.

To quote [Rene's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308472/3627607):

> There are a lot of mishaps with NAA flags. If you are unsure if your
>   NAA would be recognized when presented in isolation use a custom flag
>   instead and explain what you want to happen and why.

To complete on your comment:

> @Tensibai: I don't see how your last link should be realted, because
>   there the answer is about the topic at least. Here we have a code that
>   explains how to call an external program from java, when the question
>   was about parsing data in excell. – derM

the fact it is java is not a problem, as seen in the question there's a [java answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43592126/3627607) by the same user which seems really answering the question.
The user is new to SO (from its 1 reputation) and as such it would be better to comment and help him improve its answer instead of flagging)

Comment: Ok, so in future, if I feel the need, I will use the custom flag again. I stopped that some time ago, after receiving this response `Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see What is Flagging?` to a flag on a question, that was later indeed removed. That led me to the idea, that the *custom flag* is only for *most urgent situations* like criminal or very offensive posts.

Comment: @derM For spam/offensive there's already flags, which have an added value of triggering an auto deletion and answer ban if raised too often on someone posts. There's a meta somewhere explaining those effects

Comment: @derM Here are the effects of spam and rude/abusive flags along with  guidance for their usage: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/287976

Comment: Related: [NAA flags should show the question info to mods](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341797/naa-flags-should-show-the-key-question-info-to-mods#comment434146_341797)

Comment: @JoshCaswell I still stand by my comments there, too much added complexity/load for the system for too few cases where it would help. (And for the case here, seeing the whole thread is needed to give guidance/advice to the author)